# Tracing out where pins go on a TQFP-100 package possible?

Tags: debugging

I want to trace out some pins on my Atmega2560 based 3D printer controller board.

The problem is the particular one I have is believed to be a clone of a clone hence I don't have a schematic of the board. I can't get off the manufacturer as well. Come on it's bloody based on an open source design anyway.

Are there probes you can attach to a standard multimeter ? 
how much am I looking at?

Comment: Your multimeter should have a continuity function

Answer (score 1):

You can get really pointy probes from China for less than $5 shipped, they're a bit rough.

There are [probes](http://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/af9627752c4e78613e63892cf2d7adf2.pdf) with replacable micro-pogo pin tips from Pomona that are something like $25 a set, but they may have been obsoleted. They're quite nice, but should be stored with the protective cover in place.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for probes like [0.64mm Prüfspitzen gefedert](http://de.rs-online.com/web/p/prufspitzen/0775726/) or [MICRO-KLEPS 60](http://de.rs-online.com/web/p/klemmprufspitzen/0775697/).
The standard multimeter plug is a 4mm banana jack. For both probes are suitable cables available.